# VS 2013 Shell (Integrated) SSIS project incompatible

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, ssis

I am unable to view my SSIS projects in VS 2013.
If I try and reload the project, I get an 'Unsupported - This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects'

[image: SSIS error]

The project worked fine a couple of days ago and there were no changes done on the server so I dont know why Im receiving the error now?

All automated SQL Jobs are running successfully so the execution of the SSIS packages seems to work fine, its just viewing/altering the package which I cannot do.

Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect the SSIS package could be corrupted. I would suggest you to import SSIS packages again from the catalog and see if it is working. You can leverage Integration services import project wizard : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-ssis-projects-and-solutions?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks @VenkataramanR , could it be that all packages are corrupt? I'm unable to view any of them.

Comment: If it was working preivously, did you open using the same visual studio version (2013) or different Visual studio version (e.g., 2010) ?